# MVC3 and IIS6 RedirectToAction redirects to wrong URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

This is weird.  I have a virtual directory setup for an MVC3 application called (for the sake of this question) I'll call 'foobar'.  The full URL to this site is:

```
http://localservername.domainname.com/foobar
```

In my logon form, I have the following line that is supposed to redirect to the main/home page of the application after logon.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

However, when this line executes, I get redirected to the wrong location - so instead of redirecting me back to:

```
http://localservername.domainname.com/foobar
```

I get redirected back to:

```
http://localservername.domainname.com/foobar/foobar
```

Which of course gets me a resource not found error.  Also, any links in my views seem to do the opposite - for example if I have a link like this:

```
<a href="/WidgetSearch">Widget Search</a>
```

I would expect the following URL to open:

```
http://localservername.domainname.com/foobar/WidgetSearch
```

Instead, I get redirected to

```
http://localservername.domainname.com/WidgetSearch
```

Which of course also gets me a resource not found error.  I've never encountered this type of behaviour before.  I've gone over the basic and advanced settings and created a new application pool.  Fiddler also shows me that (of course) the URLs listed above return 404 responses.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: If you have any routes other than the default route, please show them.

Comment: did you manage to solve ur first problem? I am facing the same issue. My route is  routes.MapRoute(
             "BarCodeScan", //Route name
             "{controller}/{action}/BarCode/{*BarCode}", // URL with parameters
             new { controller = "Home", action = "ProcessBinBatchBarCode", BarCode = string.Empty } // Parameter defaults
            );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue shouldn't really happen. `RedirectToAction` should take into account your virtual directory path (you haven't hard coded an extra `/foobar` into your route setup have you?).

The second problem has nothing to do with MVC, it's just that you're using a vanilla HTML link that is pointing directly to the root of the server (that's what saying `/blah` implies). You should change your link to use one of the MVC helper methods to generate the URL instead to make sure it adds the virtual directory for you. So one of the following (the first is probably the best way, unless you need to heavily customise what the anchor tag looks like):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Widget Search", "Index", "WidgetSearch")
```

or

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "WidgetSearch")">Widget Search</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll update the links this evening.  But that first one has me stumped - a real head scratcher.

Comment: @AndyEvans - Only thing I can think of is your route setup... What do your route registrations look like? Do you have anything other than the normal default `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"` one? There should be no mention of your virtual directory `/foobar` anywhere in your code as that should be being handled by the underlying framework.

Comment: You are correct.  No where in my project does /foobar appear.  This is aggravating.